# Setting just the year with PHP DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

With PHP [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) you can use methods such as `->modify()` `->add()` and `->sub()` to manipulate the current DateTime object.

There are also `->setDate()` and `->setTime()` methods which allow updating of the year, month and day, or the hour, minute and second.

There doesn't however appear to be any way to just set the year, month or day alone.

Am I right in thinking that the best method is to create a new DateTime object and use the previous object to populate the `setDate()` method?

Something like this:

```php
$DateTime2020 = new \DateTime('2020-02-26');
$DateTime2019 = (new \DateTime())->setDate('2019', $DateTime2020->format('m'), $DateTime2020->format('d'));
```

Comment: can you explain the what should be the expected/desired result ?

Comment: Your date $DateTime2019 has the current time: For example "2019-02-26 19:51:58.614030". Do you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$DateTime2020 = new \DateTime('2020-02-26');

$year = 2019;

$DateTime2019 = date_create($DateTime2020->format($year."-m-d"));
// 2019-02-26 00:00:00.000000
```

Comment: I knew there was a shortcut there somewhere! Thanks. Can also be ... `$DateTime2019 = new \DateTime($DateTime2020->format($year."-m-d"));`

Answer (score 4):

You can use same notation as in `->format()` method, so you don't need to create object and modify it later. Below is an example:

`new \DateTime("$year-01-01")` for dynamic year

`new \DateTime("this year $month/01")` for dynamic month

[All possible values you can find here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Basically DateTime object requires all segments to be valid, and during create new object php try to guess the segments using constructor's parameter (by default is 2020-01-01 00:00:00), but when you set DateTime(2019) php recognises it as hours:minutes (20:19) so you have to be more specific, thats why i've added 01-01 which refers to month & day.