# How to set just the year of a DateTime using the modify method?

Tags: php, datetime

According to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), it should be possible to change only the year component of a `DateTime` using the [`modify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimeimmutable.modify.php) method. However, this only seems to work for years whose century is between 60-99.

```php
(new DateTime)->modify('1960')->format('c'); // '1960-01-25T19:09:44+00:00'
```

If the century is between 00-59 (inclusive), it is instead interpreted as a time.

```php
(new DateTime)->modify('1959')->format('c'); // '2024-01-25T19:59:00+00:00'
```

That seems fair enough; the parser cannot tell if we intended a date or time otherwise.

How can we force the parser to interpret our input as a year? According to the documentation for [compound formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.compound), a literal `T` should differentiate between the date and time parts of the input.

```php
(new DateTime)->modify('1959T')->format('c'); // '2024-01-25T19:59:00+00:00'
```

Simply specifying `T` with no suffix has no effect.

```php
(new DateTime)->modify('1959T0000')->format('c'); // '0000-01-25T19:59:00+00:00'
```

This assumes we don't care about the time part of the date because we're expecting it to be set to midnight as a side-effect of setting the year. However, that's not what happens: it sets the *year* to `0000` and still takes `1959` as the time. Being as that's the case, we can invert this and get the desired result.

```php
// Note that `T` is interchangeable with a space here.
(new DateTime)->modify('0000 1959')->format('c'); // '1959-01-25T00:00:00+00:00'
```

This *works* (with the side-effect of setting the time) but how could we ever have the reasonable expectation that this *should* work (or will continue to work in future)? In absolutely none of the valid, documented compound formats does the time ever appear before the date, so why do we have to specify them in reverse order?

Any further attempts to *force* the interpreter to treat `0000` as a time specifier *after* the date results in parse failures because it thinks we're specifying the time twice.

```php
(new DateTime)->modify('1959T00:00')->format('c');
(new DateTime)->modify('1959T00:00:00')->format('c');
// DateTime::modify(): Failed to parse time string (1959T00:00:00) at position 4 (T): Double time specification
```

I'm aware there are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415815/setting-just-the-year-with-php-datetime) about setting just the year, but this question is asking whether there is any incantation of `modify()`, specifically, that will set just the year. The accepted answer otherwise involves explicitly setting the month and day again, which is inelegant and should not be necessary.

Although `'0000 1959'` appears to be a valid way to set just the year, it can be improved in one of two ways:

- This incantation appears to be undocumented. A documented way to achieve the same would be a valid improvement.
- The proposed incantation has the unwanted side-effect of modifying the time. An alternative that *only* changes the year would be a valid improvement.

Aside, it would be interesting if someone familiar with internals could comment on why `'0000 1959'`/`'0000T1959'` is parsed in the demonstrated manner (i.e. time before date), which [has not changed since it was first implemented](https://3v4l.org/MPR99).

Comment: why don't you use `setDate`?

Comment: Or just `date("Y {other params}")`?  what's the purpose of what you are trying to do?  Functionality or curiousity?

Comment: Also --  *" inelegant and should not be necessary"* is subjective, and completely opinion based.

Comment: Notwithstanding my opinion would not be invalidated if this were a merely an opinion, as it is my prerogative to set the parameters for the question, but setting _month_ and _day_ to the same values is objectively wasted CPU cycles and characters on screen as well as on disk, and thus not merely opinion.

Comment: Why do you need to change the year of an exising date anyway (with an absolute value)? That's not common.

Comment: *"same values is objectively wasted CPU cycles  and characters on screen as well as on disk"*   --   If you have to split hairs like this to save overhead .. You need some more CPU allocation my friend.  Otherwise Tom-aye-toe to-mah-toe --  I say you're having an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Specifically in answer #2 *"Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like a strange problem to want to solve. --
After much interaction and wasted time, it finally becomes clear that the user really wants help with X, and that Y wasn't even a suitable solution for X."*

Comment: `setDate()` requires repeating the month and day.

Answer (score 2):

ISO8601 format string *shorthand* is `c`, but the full expression is `Y-m-d\TH:i:sO`. [see: `DateTime::ISO9601`]

You can simply modify this format string to include a static year, eg:

```php
(new DateTime)->format("1959-m-d\TH:i:sO")
```

Though I would only really suggest this for outputting formatted strings, as re-interpreting a rendered date/time string can be troublesome in itself.

If you want to modify the DateTime object for other use I would suggest the `setDate()` method instead as `modify()` seems to rely on the "guess what the input var is supposed to represent", which is seldom a good idea to rely on. Eg:

```php
($d = new DateTime)->setDate(1959, (int)$d->format('m'), (int)$d->format('d'))
```

Aside from that the other options would be using `add()` or `sub()` with relevant DateInterval objects, but I get the impression that that is even further away from what you'd want.

Comment: You are not answering the question. I am using `format('c')` as a convenience to you so you can see the effect of `modify()`. It has no bearing on the problem space whatsoever.

Comment: Hence the second and third parts of the answer.

Comment: The remainder of your answer elides the imperative constraints, and worse, just reiterates the knowledge already shared in the question.

Comment: @QuolonelQuestions The answer implicitly answers your question, by saying "you can't, but you can do it this way instead".

Comment: No proof has been proffered to substantiate that _you can't_.